# values_list() in query_set is showing only numbers but not the names of countries

Tags: python, django

I selected my field with 'values_list' which contains name of countries.  But what I get is country_id numbers.

I already used flat=True but it did not help any.

my models.py:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    church_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    water_baptism = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    holy_ghost = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.area

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:report_view')
```

my views.py:

```
def report_cities(request, pk):
    countries = Report.objects.values_list('country', flat=True)

    context = {
        'countries':countries
    }
    return render(request, 'users/report_countries.html', context)
```

my html

```
  <h1>Report Countries</h1>

  {% for country in countries %}
  {{country}}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Report.objects.values_list('country__name', flat=True)` (assuming that is the country name field on the country model). By default django will list the object id if no field is specified.

E.G if your country model was

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = Charfield()
    another_field = ...
```

The above query would now return a list of the names.